# Command not found when running swapon with SSH

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to use "swapon -s" remotely but getting "command not found"

```
$ ssh ns2 swapon -s 
bash: swapon: command not found
```

Using it locally works perfectly, what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several possible reasons:

1. You're not root at the remote side. Check this with `who am i` or `id`. To make sure you're root, use `ssh root@ns2 ...`
2. Your path is wrong. This is often a problem with `sudo`. Try `ssh ns2 sudo /sbin/swapon`

Comment: 1. Doesn't work with sudo
2. We have a winner!
Thanks

Comment: There is no "sudo" in your question ... so what are you talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about using "ssh ns2 sudo swapon", which doesn't work as well.

Comment: If you use `root@ns2`, you don't need `sudo`.

Comment: Aaron, the revision you just made made it clear that you're completely misunderstanding me. Nevertheless you managed to help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to ran

```
which swapon
```

If it returns something like
`no swapon in (/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:...)` 
it means that swapon script isn't found anywhere

Comment: if not found how can we enable it? and how can we change the swapfile location or size?

Comment: mine was not found at all

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're not in the sudoers file or you need to enter a password.

Be sure that you're really root so try try this and look if it differs:

```
ssh server.tld id
ssh server.tld sudo id
```

The second one should give you an output which should be this:

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

If this is not the output check your /etc/suders which should have an entry like this:

```
foo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

The command I runned and which worked:

```
ssh -l foo server.tld sudo swapon -s
```